# (React/Redux) Dispatching 2 actions after a resolved promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, es6-promise

I got a promise, which after it resolves I want to dispatch two different actions to two different 
reducers.

This code breaks :

```
 axios
    .post('http://localhost:4000/api/users/saveUser', user, config)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_USER,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    )
```

How should I do it right?

Comment: You're returning dispatch in the first `then` which is passed as `res` in the second `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dispatch both of them in the same then block.

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:4000/api/users/saveUser', user, config)
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  })
  .catch((err) =>
    dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
  );
```

Otherwise at the end of the first then block, you'd need to return res so that the second then block has access to res.

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:4000/api/users/saveUser', user, config)
  .then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    return res;
  })
  .then((res) =>
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    })
  )
  .catch((err) =>
    dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
  );
```